# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [159, 40]

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to ML. Trying out the Linear Regression and facing the below error. Please help me to resolve it.
Here is my code:

```
  x=dataset.iloc[:,1:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred=regressor.predict(x_test)
```

x.shape is [199,2] and y.shape is [199,].
after the execution of the code i getting the below error:
**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [159, 40]**

Answer (score 3):

The order of the splits from `train_test_split` looks wrong. It should be:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Comment: got it...Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @RaviRanjan no problem, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was helpful ;-)